# How to create a multi column report/ cross tab query using Microsoft access

Tags: vba, ms-access, crosstab

I'm trying to achieve a report that looks similar to this using a cross tab query in Microsoft Access. Do i need to make individual queries first then join them together?

[image]

Comment: Hey Jake! On this site users are supposed to ask fairly specific and focused questions that requires code or programming knowledge. This means that your question should have some code, what languages you'd be using, etc. for the community to actually be helpful to you. Check out the rules here for more clarification: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28679/the-rules-of-stack-overflow

Answer (score 0):

In MSaccess you cannot create a crosstab with 2 column headers, You can create with 2 row headers, but you cannot create 2 column headers.

If a 2 row headers work for you, then you can do a query like:

```
TRANSFORM Count(Table2.ID) AS CountOfID
SELECT Table2.PRODUCT, Table2.QUARTER
FROM Table2
GROUP BY Table2.PRODUCT, Table2.QUARTER
PIVOT Table2.TYPE;
```